# Display a countdown in a ZSH script?

Tags: shell, timeout, zsh

I have a zsh script where I read input from the user and I default to 'yes' after some time.

I'm currently doing this with something like `read -q -tt 5`. Here's the actual code:

```
echo "${Red}Errors${RegF} were detected in the output of $i."
read -q -tt $CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT "REPLY?Proceed? [Yn] "
echo
case $REPLY in
    'N') ;&
    'n') echo "Aborting..."; exit 0;;
    *) ;;
esac
```

And I get:

```
Errors were detected in the output of groups.xml.
Proceed? [Yn]
```

But I would like to display a countdown on the screen, maybe something like

```
Errors were detected in the output of groups.xml.
Proceed? [Yn] (5)
```

With that number decreasing every second.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thank you!

PS: I also appreciate comments on stuff that can be done in a better way in this code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
echo "${Red}Errors${RegF} were detected in the output of $i."
{ i=$CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT; while test $((i--)) -ge 0; do 
  printf "\rREPLY?Proceed? [Yn] ($i)"; sleep 1; done; } &

read -q -tt $CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT
kill $!
echo
case $REPLY in
    'N') ;&
    'n') echo "Aborting..."; exit 0;;
    *) ;;
esac
```